# Special Metric in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, spherical-geometry

So I sat down and thoroughly calculated the Christoffel Symbols and Ricci tensor for the following 2-dimensional metric:

$$g_{xx}=R^2\frac{1-y^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2},\,g_{yy}=R^2\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2},\,g_{xy}=g_{yx}=R^2\frac{xy}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$$

where $x^2+y^2<1$.

In the book I found this metric, it was mentioned that for this metric the distance between two points is unbounded. It turns out that the Ricci scalar is $R=-\frac{2}{R^2}$. So I am troubled with two things:

(1) Why is the distance between two objects unbounded when the space is described by that metric?
(2) Is there any connection between the surface of a 2-d sphere and this particular metric?

Comment: Just want to double-check. The metric looks quite familiar to me *if* you are missing a squared in the denominators, i.e., $(1-x^2-y^2)^2$ throughout. I just want to be sure this is what you intend. Also, your coordinates are defined on the open unit disk?

Comment: Yeah you are totally right! Sorry for my mistake. I mention now where I define my coordinates as well. Finally, I corrected a minus sign in the ricci scalar. Do you still think this corresponds to a hemisphere?

Comment: Oh, no. With the squares, this is the Klein-Beltrami model of the hyperbolic plane!!! And then your curvature computation gives constant negative curvature!

Comment: Of course.. negative curvature! But still I am not sure I understand the term unbounded distance between two points.

Comment: Do the same path I suggested in my answer for the other metric. You'll see the length goes to $\infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've double-checked your computations (with assistance from Mathematica). The Gauss equations do give $K=1$ with $R=1$. I believe this is just an open-disk model for a hemisphere using a combination of orthogonal projection and stereographic projection. The surface is not complete, but certainly the distances stay bounded. (For example, check the metric is rotationally symmetric about the origin. Now compute the length of the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1-\epsilon,0)$ and you'll see this approaches $\pi/2$, as it should.)